# How to check Checkboxes in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have a list of objects as an `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`. I am already able to display the *name* property of these objects in a combobox using XAML within a DataGrid.

Now I have another object `AnotherObject` which has a property that is defined as a list of strings and each item of that list is the *name* property of MyObject mentioned above.

In the combobox I want to display the `MyObject.name` property preceeded by a checkbox. 
Let's say that there are 30 items in the checkbox and an instance of `AnotherObject.names` holds three of them. 
Now I want select the checkboxes of those items that are equal to the three items in `AnotherObject.names`.

How can I achieve this?

Some code:

MyObjectViewModel.cs:

```
public class MyObjectViewModel
{
    private MyObject _myObject;

    public MyObjectViewModel(MyObject myObject)
    {
        this._myObject = myObject;
    }

    public MyObject MyObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _myObject;
        }
        set
        {
            _myObject = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _myObject.Name;  }
        set
        {
            _myObject.Name = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

AnotherObjectRowViewmodel.cs:

```
public class AnotherObjectRowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private AnotherObject _anotherObject;
    private ObservableCollection<MyObjectViewModel> _myObjects;

    public AnotherObjectRowViewModel(AnotherObject anotherObject, ObservableCollection<MyObjectViewModel> myObjects)
    {
        this._anotherObject = anotherObject;
        this._myObjects = myObjects;
    }

    public AnotherObject AnotherObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _anotherObject;
        }
        set
        {
            this._anotherObject = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _anotherObject.Name; }
        set { _anotherObject.Name = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyObjectViewModel> MyObjects {
        get
        {
            return this._myObjects;
        }
        set
        {
            _myObjects = value;
        }
    }

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        remove
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I tried in the XAML file:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="NamesColumn" Header="Names">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox Name="Name" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myObjects}" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="OnDetailParamsSelectionChanged" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="chbNames" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="OnChbDetailParamsCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnChbDetailParamsCheckBoxChecked"></CheckBox>
                                <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Path=MyObject}" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource StringListConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**An example:**
The combobox holds a list of 30 names (Name1, ..., Name30);

AnotherObject.names is { Name1, Name2, Name4, Name7 };

In the combobox the selected items shall be Name1, Name2, Name4, Name7. All other items shall stay unselected.

**Update 2019-01-06:**
This means that the Combobox's ItemsSource={Binding} is *MyObject* but the checked items shall be stored in *AnotherObject*. This is why I get this exception whenever I tick a checkbox:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'xxx' property not found on 'object' ''MyObjectViewModel' (HashCode=34649765)'. BindingExpression:Path=xxx.DetailParams; DataItem='MyObjectViewModel' (HashCode=34649765); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name='chbDetailParams'); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
```

My XAML contains thefollowing code snippet according to the *IsItemsSelectedConverter*:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ctb:IsItemSelectedConverter x:Key="IsItemSelectedConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The checkboxes IsChecked property looks like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=Names, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource IsItemSelectedConverter}}"
```

but it doesn't work. Debugging this code, the IsItemsSelectedConverter is never used.

Comment: Can you post code outlining these structures? I think I understand what you're looking for but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I can't see a `Names` in your code. and I'm sure you can simplify your question **more** before asking it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Boolean property in the view model of `MyObject`, i.e. in `MyObjectViewModel` that will return a value if `Name` is in the list of names in `AnotherObject`.

Comment: Well, I think this may work if anotherObject.names is just a single string but not a list of strings. Please note the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an IsItemSelectedConverter and pass in the list of objects from your data model. Implement [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert?view=netframework-4.7.2) in a new class and bind the IsChecked property for each checkbox to two things: value should be the current item, and parameter should be the list of items. The converter should determine whether the current item is in the list of items and return the appropriate boolean.

You will have to create an instance of the Converter for the UI to use. I usually define converters in a separate Resource Dictionary that I make globally available for all XAML files.

My IsItemSelectedConverter looks like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (value is MyObjectViewModel objectViewModel && parameter is AnotherObjectRowViewModel anotherObjectRowViewModel)
            {
                return anotherObjectRowViewModel.MyObjects.Contains(objectViewModel);
            }
            return false;
        }
```

On the XAML, my CheckBox code looks like this: `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource viewModel} }" />`

Please note: there are a few problems with the code that will prevent it from running as is, but I'm assuming these are artifacts of copying and pasting your actual code.

Comment: I guess I see what you suggest but how can I do that? How can I bind a Checkbox' IsChecked property to the Names list in AnotherObject and the MyObject as well? Some code?? :-) 
When I try to use {Binding...} in conjunction with ConverterParameter it results in: 
XamlParseException: Binding can not be set for the Binding ConverterParameter property. Binding can only be set for a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: Make sure your Window.Resources (or another linked Resource Dictionary) contains an IsItemsSelectedConverter called "converter". Your IsChecked expression on the CheckBox will look something like this: 
`IsChecked="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource converter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource viewModel} }"`. I'm not sure how you're storing the View Model, so you'll have to adjust accordingly.